# how to change http to https in wsdl port wcf

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am working on wcf service and ssl offloading environment. so i have to setup http binding through custom binding...

please look below wsdl:port

```
<wsdl:service name="sample">
<wsdl:port name="httpsProxyEndPoint" binding="httpsProxyEndPoint">
<soap:address location="http://sample.portal.co.in/sample.svc/api"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Now I want to change location with https

```
<wsdl:service name="sample">
<wsdl:port name="httpsProxyEndPoint" binding="httpsProxyEndPoint">
<soap:address location="https://sample.portal.co.in/sample.svc/api"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>`enter code here`
```

Comment: ...and what went wrong? What do you want help with?

Comment: Matt, I want to change soap address's protocal http with https

currently I have 

`<soap:address location="http://sample.portal.co.in/sample.svc/api"/>`

but i need to replace http with **https**

Answer (score 0):

You likely need a protocolMapping in the config for the service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="httpsProxyEndpoint" scheme="https" />
        <add binding="httpsProxyEndpoint" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
</system.serviceModel>
```